# Roslyn: Missing method exception for VSIX package

Tags: c#, roslyn, vsix

I have problems since I have updated "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting" to 1.3.2.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a VS add-in with EditorMargin class.
2. Change .NET to 4.6
3. Install Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting and Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.
4. Put somewhere in ctor the following code:

   ```
   var t = new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary)
   ```

After running the add-in it will throw a

> Missing method exception

It cannot find a constructor of `CSharpCompilationOptions`. I noticed that when I don't install "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting" (which is not necessary in the above case), everything works. I guess one of dependencies of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting installs some packages.

I tried to run "Fuslogvw" to see if there are any binding errors but I could not find anything useful.

Any ideas?

**Update**
- I use Visual Studio 2015 update 3

**Update 2**
I downgraded "System.Collections.Immutable" from 1.2.0 to 1.1.37 and it works again. 
**Update 3**
I found the reported bug:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/12247

The problem is I need to use 1.2.0 because Roslyn scripting API uses that version.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio 2015 are you using?

Comment: It's update 3. I can prepare a sample to show the exception. Would it be useful?

Comment: Not a binding error so you have to log all binds.  And you'll have to look in devenv.exe.config, it is the one that decides what version is going to get loaded since the IDE uses these assemblies as well.  Kinda tricky when just about every update will break your addin btw, you might want to wait until Roslyn stabilizes a bit.  A year or two :)

Answer (score 1):

The current workaround for me is to downgrade Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Csharp.Scripting to the version which works with "System.Collections.Immutable 1.1.37"

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting package version 1.3.2, that means you're targeting Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, but I'm guessing you don't have that installed. Either downgrade to an older version (i.e. 1.2 if you're targeting Update 2, 1.1 if targeting Update 1), or upgrade your VS to a newer version.

Comment: I use VS 2015 Update 3.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this problem installing Visual Studio 2017. VS 2017 requires System.Collection.Immutable 1.2.1.0, which does not conflict with other Roslyn versions